# How can I listen on Dimension.get('window').height within a component so when user rotate or web user resize, the layout can reflow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-web

How can I listen on `Dimension.get('window').height` within a component so when user rotate the device or the web user resize the browser window then my layout can reflow?

I have checked existing HoC, but haven't found one, a lib would also be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The React Native [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions) mention a `addEventListener` on the `Dimensions` API. You just need to pass it a function and whenever this is triggered, use `setState` to update whatever values you need.

You could use it like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

class DimensionsWrapper extends Component {

    state = {
        landscape : Dimensions.get('window').height < Dimensions.get('window').width
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Dimensions.addEventListener('change', this._onDimensionsChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', this._onDimensionsChange);
    }

    _onDimensionsChange(event) {
        const { width, height } = event.window; 
        const landscape = height < width;

        this.setState({ landscape }); 
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I have already something to get the orientation within expo SDK36 which I am using https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-do-styling-with-expo-and-react-native-paper-based-on-device-orientation/32454/2?u=kopax . I want to makes it an HoC, do you know if one exist ? This will also work for window resize on the web ?